# Is this sentence correct: ''my father is my favorite personality.''

Tags: personality

In the Indian subcontinent, we're accustomed to saying sentences like:

1. Who is your favorite personality?
2. My father is my favorite personality.
3. You are a dynamic personality.
4. You are a great personality.
5. He was a dynamic personality in the business world.
6. Abraham Lincoln is my favorite personality.

But I believe, the correct versions would be:

1. Who is your favorite person?
2. My father is my favorite person.
3. You have a dynamic personality.
4. You are a great personality.
5. He has a dynamic personality in the business world.
6. Abraham Lincoln is my favorite political personality.

Please help me with your thoughts and explanations. Thank you.

Comment: The British or American versions are not 'correct' and the Indian ones are not 'incorrect'. They are just _favored_ in one place or another. That said, having little experience with Indian English, I can't tell if these pairs correspond exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two meanings of *personality.* (3)and (4) (and possibly (5)) relate to "the combination of characteristics or qualities that form an individual's distinctive character" (definition from Oxford Dictionaries via Google).

The other meaning is "a celebrity or famous person". You are right in thinking that it isn't appropriate to use that term of your father or of a historical figure such as Abraham Lincoln.